# Laravel 4 Blade markup and Ide Helper in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I cannot manage to have the autocomplete in PhpStorm to work for the Laravel 4 blade.php files.
I've searched everywhere, but I cannot find other users with my problem. I have correctly installed this repository at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper but I still get a blank formatting for the blade pages.

Thanks

Comment: This is the 6th most popular issue on JetBrains issue tracker just now: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A+PhpStorm+sort+by%3A+Votes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The laravel-ide-helper package is not designed to give you autocomplete in the blade.php files. The laravel-ide-helper package is designed to give you autocomplete for the laravel facades in other PHP files.

PHPstorm does not know that code between `{{ }}` and `{{{ }}}` is PHP code so it does not know  that it should provide autocomplete ability.

There is an issue on the PHPstorm Issue Tracker for [syntax highlighting for the blade templating language](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14172) that you should add your voice to if you wish for JetBrains to implement this feature.

Comment: What about the formatting option? I see all these tutorials where the @something are coded in red, while for me it isn't.

Comment: They are probably using sublime text which has packages built for it. PHPstorm does support these packages however there are caviets: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14172#comment=27-527043

Answer (score 2):

As for PHPstorm 9 you just have to change the settings for blade files to recognize Laravel's tags as follows:

[image: Settings]